# Creating 3d HSV cone model in java

Tags: java, javafx, graphic

Could anyone tell me how to create hsv cone model in java. I allready created 3d rgb Cube in JavaFX using 6 rectangles with Image, but i haven't found anything about creating cone. Could give me any advice how to do that and if its not possible in javaFX which library i should use? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this library.
http://birdasaur.github.io/FXyz/
Search for the word cone on this page.